# onFocusChangeListener event after onStop with EditText in Android

Tags: android

I am using `onFocusChangeListener` to track when the user has finished editing an `edittext` inside a fragment.  In certain cases, based on the user input, this triggers a ringtone alarm to start playing.  The ringtone alarm continues until another event triggers it to stop, such as another edit in the `edittext` field or if the fragment is exited, through `onStop()`.
It seems that the `onFocusChange` listener gets called again AFTER `onStop()`, which is problematic because it can trigger the ringtone alarm again, and won't stop even if the application is closed.

in `onCreateView`, set listener:

```
     mTextEdit = (EditText) rootView
            .findViewById(R.id.userInput);
     mTextEdit.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
```

and

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
  // stop alarm from sounding if fragment is stopped.
    stopAlarm(); 
}

@Override
public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {

    if (!hasFocus) { // Only do when exiting focus

        if (view.getId()==R.id.userInput)
          {   startAlarm(); // method to start ringtone alarm }
    }
}

private void startAlarm() {

    // stop existing ringtone
    if (mAlarmManager != null) {   stopAlarm();   }

    // set and play new ring tone
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "Ringtone: " + mAlarmURI.toString());
        mAlarmManager = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getActivity(), mAlarmURI);
        mAlarmManager.play();
        Log.d(TAG, "Alarm is playing");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // failed to get/play ringtone
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void stopAlarm() {
    if (mAlarmManager != null)
        try {
            mAlarmManager.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // failed to stop ringtone
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to stop ringtone.");
        }
    mAlarmManager = null;
}
```

Comment: could you specify more relevant code?

Comment: did you trying stopAlarm() method in onDestroy() and onPause() methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Rushi, I think I have my answer.  It's not pretty.  I need to stop the alarm in two places, onStop() and onDestroy() because the state cycle can be different for different events.

If the user navigates to a preference setting and back:

```
onPause()
onStop() - stop alarm here
onResume()
```

if the user navigates out of the fragment:

```
onPause()
onStop() - stop alarm here
onFocusChange() - alarm is retriggered
onDestroy() - stop alarm again
```